# Short story involving a dwarf with exoskeleton armour and a powered axe

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I remember reading this at least 15 years ago.  Four or five protagonists, one was a dwarf with exoskeleton armor and an axe.  Axe may have been powered also.  I seem to think the dwarf's name may have started with a 'G'. Probably irrelevant, but I think I was reading lot of Robert Lynn Aspirin about that time period.

Comment: Hi there. That's some info already; but maybe you could take a look at [these guidelines on story-ID](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/98028), see if they trigger any more memories you could [edit] in? For instance, did you read that online, in an anthology, any recollection of the cover? Stuff like that, however minor it may seem, might help track it down. Cheers :)

Answer (score 6):

Possibly one of the [Viriconium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viriconium) stories by M. John Harrison?  They were published in he 70s-early 80s.  One of the characters is named "Tomb the Iron Dwarf".  He wears a powered exoskeleton. For example in The Pastel City there is the description:

> To his left, Tomb the Dwarf towered above the Northmen in his exoskeleton, a deadly, glittering, giant insect, kicking in faces with bloodshod metal feet, striking terror and skulls with his horrible axe.

And the aforementioned *horrible axe* is indeed a powered weapon. Earlier in this story we read:

> The black eyes flickered warily round the walls. They touched briefly on a powered battle-axe that Cromis had got from his friend Tomb the Dwarf after the sea fight at Mingulay in the Rivermouth campaign.

Comment: Could it be Flight of Honor by Richard S McEnroe - one of the main protagonists ( Oin Ceiragh ) is from a heavy gravity world so is dwarflike in appearance, and has powered armour

Comment: I have the Viriconium books so I've added supporting quotes. Please feel free to roll back my edits if you don't like them.

Comment: The memory of the dwarf's name beginning with "G" could be a confusion with that most infamous of lunatic axe wielding dwarves [Gotrek](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gotrek_and_Felix).

Comment: @JohnRennie Thanks for the quotes. I can't seem to find my copy, and had forgotten that the dwarf's axe was powered!

Comment: @JohnRennie "most infamous of lunatic axe wielding dwarves:... Gimli? ;)

Comment: @lexible "most infamous of lunatic axe wielding dwarves":... Grumpy? ;-)